# Create Cells starting at date x and ending at date y

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet I'm working on, that looks up data from a database based on the date/time.  I have a row set up with the starting date/time and want to create a script or macro that will automatically copy that row, I'll call it the guide row, and add x minutes until it hits an end time.

I need to copy the entire guide row (row 5) add x minutes (which you can define in cell D3) and copy them as many times until the time value (located in Column G of every row) equals the end time (located in G2).

Comment: This has a lot of useful information: http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/MainPage.aspx

Comment: try [The Spreadsheet Page by John Walkenbach](http://spreadsheetpage.com/) or [Mr Excel](http://www.mrexcel.com/) or [Excel User](http://www.exceluser.com/explore/index.htm)

Comment: also take a look at [McGimpsey & Associates](http://www.mcgimpsey.com/excel/index.html) or [Ozgrid.com](http://www.ozgrid.com/)

Comment: Sorry pnuts, as I said in the title, while I have programming experience, I'm not familiar with excel VBA, hence I didn't even have an idea of where to start.  The helpful answers provided gave me the starting points to figure it out, I'll post the code I worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Transfer answer added by OP to question during period OP could not post own answer:*

Here's the code I worked out from the helpful links in my question:

```
Sub PopCells()
' Define Variables
Dim RowLast As Long 'Last Row with Data in it
Dim CpRange As String 'Holds range of data to select when using a variable

' Find the Last Row with Data in it
RowLast = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

' Clear out old range of data
Let CpRange = "H6:ZZ" & RowLast
ActiveSheet.Range(CpRange).Select
Selection.ClearContents

' Set the current row to the first row with Data
CrRow = 5

' Loop copies the current row, pastes it to the following row
' And increments the time frame by the time increament value
While Cells(CrRow, "H") <= [G2]
    ' Select the entire current row
    Let CpRange = "H" & CrRow & ":" & "ZZ" & CrRow
    ActiveSheet.Range(CpRange).Select

    'Copy Selected Row
    Selection.Copy

    ' Increment to the Next Row
    CrRow = CrRow + 1

    ' Select the entire current row
    Let CpRange = "H" & CrRow & ":" & "ZZ" & CrRow
    ActiveSheet.Range(CpRange).Select
    ' Paste in copied row
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    ' Update time
    ActiveSheet.Cells(CrRow, "H") = ActiveSheet.Cells(CrRow - 1, "H") + [$D$3] / 1440
Wend


End Sub
```

Comment: @Abishur - I'm afraid I'm unclear on whether this is a final solution or not. Are you asking to help to improve it or should this be considered the answer as it stands?

Comment: This is the final answer, it was originally part of the original post.  I was able to find the answer from the comments to the OP but could not post an answer because I was new to the site and not enough time had passed yet since I first asked the question.  User @pnuts was nice enough to move it into a unique post for me.